# how to export in csv format instead of .iqy

Tags: export, csv

By default export to spreadsheet showing owssvr.iqy , we need to have owssvr.csv
Please help.

Comment: SharePoint does not export to CSV, IQY is an Excel query to the SharePoint list.  You can do the export to CSV from Excel. There may be some Apps in the Microsoft Store that do a direct export.

Answer (score 3):

By default SharePoint only support IQY format, In order to export the list into csv you have to use the 3rd party tools or run some kind of script.

[for 2010](https://meandmysharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/08/export-sharepoint-list-data-into-csv.html)

```
$spSiteUrl = "http://sharepointwebapplication"
$listtitle="My Custom List"
$spWeb= Get-SPWeb -Identity $spSiteUrl
Function ImportDataFromListToCSV
{
  IF($spWeb -ne $null)
  {
  $list = $spWeb.Lists.TryGetList($listtitle)
  $exportlist = @()
  $items = $list.Items
  Write-Host "Exporting........" -ForegroundColor Yellow
  if($items -ne $null)
  { 
    #Here "givenName" column name for CSV file and "Given Name" column name SharePoint List
    $items | %{ select-object -input $_ -prop @{Name='givenName';expression={$_["Given     Name"];}},@{Name='surname';expression={$_["Family Name"];}};}| Export-Csv -Path C:\Demo.csv -NoTypeInformation 
    Write-Host "SharePoint list data is exported successfully." -ForegroundColor Green
    $spWeb.Dispose()
 }
 Else
 {Write-Host "No data found in the list "$listtitle -ForegroundColor Yellow}}
}
```

[2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797004/powershell-sharepoint-export-list-items-via-view-to-csv)

```
Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") | out-null
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://yoursite")
$web = $site.RootWeb
$list = $web.Lists[$listname]
$view = $list.Views["Current Month"] 
$items = $list.GetItems($view)
$items | %{ select-object -input $_ -prop @{Name='Title';expression={$_.Title;}}, @{Name='Check Number';expression={$_["Check Number"];}}; } | Export-Csv -Path c:\test.csv
```

[Export SharePoint List Items to CSV using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-csv-using-powershell.html#ixzz3tIUCvuWx)

Read more: